# How to reference by ID and Discriminator in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'd like to reference Contacts of different types per reference object.
I have the given EF structure I would like to expand.

```
public class Contact {}
public class Customer : Contact {}
public class Salesperson : Contact {}
public class Producer : Contact {}
public class ContactPerson : Contact {}
```

It's code first and the database contains following tables: Customers, Salespersons, Producers and ContactPersons (no Contact Table).

Now I want to create references between these entities. E.g. Child-Parent relation between two customers or to set a contact person for a Customer or a Producer. And I want use one relation class for these different relations.

My idea was to create a ContactRelation like this:

```
public enum RelationRole : short {
   Child,
   ContactPerson,
   Head
}

public class ContactRelation {
   Guid ParentId { get; set; }
   string ParentType { get; set; }
   Guid ChildId { get; set; }
   string ChildType { get; set; }
   RelationRole Role { get; set; }
}
```

But I would like to make the relations really referencing the Contacts, so I can to handle them easily. Is there a way to teach EF this kind of reference? I would need something like this (in every ContactType)

```
public class Customer : Contact {
   [ForeignKey("ParentId")]
   //PSEUDO CODE! How to achieve something like this???
   [Discriminator("ParentType", "Customer")] 
   public ICollection<ContactRelations> Children { get; set; }
   [ForeignKey("ChildId")]
   //PSEUDO CODE! How to achieve something like this???
   [Discriminator("ChildType", "Customer")] 
   public ICollection<ContactRelations> Children { get; set; }
}
```

How can I teach this to EF and make to set the type correctly when adding ContactRelations to the collection?

**EDIT** maybe last part better should be part of the base class Contact